# Does anyone know how to deploy Case Management (caseman) in CumulusCI?

Tags: deployment, npsp

Trying to deploy Case Management for a Client. They have licenses, but I can't get the dependencies to flow right. It's saying I'm missing Action Plan, but I don't know where to get packaging info for that package. There is an unpackaged version on Salesforce Labs, but I don't think that's the right one.

Update of InstalledPackage caseman: Error:
(ActionPlanTemplateGroupItem__c.ActionPlanTemplate__c)
referenceTo value of 'ActionPlanTemplate' does not resolve to a valid sObject
type, Details: ActionPlanTemplateGroupItem__c.ActionPlanTemplate__c:
referenceTo value of 'ActionPlanTemplate' does not resolve to a valid sObject

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain on this, but my strong hunch is that your scratch org is missing the IndustriesActionPlan feature which is making those Action Plans related objects not visible in your scratch org:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_industriesactionplan